# Received "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment" when the variable was initialized

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x, while-loop

**[Community edit to give reproducible example:]**

```
def main():
    e = None
    print(locals())
    while not e:
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            pass            

main()
```

produces

```
~/coding$ python3.3 quiz2.py
{'e': None}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quiz2.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "quiz2.py", line 5, in main
    while not e:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
```

---

[EDITED] to include a reproducible code

I am trying to run a while-loop, and the condition I use is that the loop continues when the variable `e==None`. The relevant code is below:

```
    print("\nThe current score list contains the following people's scores: ")
    score_list = open("score_list.dat", "rb")
    score_name = []
    e = None
    while not e:
        try:
            score = pickle.load(score_list)
            name = pickle.load(score_list)
            score_name.append([score, name])
        except EOFError as e:
            pass            
    score_list_sorted=sorted(score_list)
    sort_list.close()
    for item in score_list_sorted:
        print("Score: ", item[0], "\t", item[1])
```

the complete code is here: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/llj5xwexzfsoppv/stats_quiz_feb24_2013.py`

The data file it requires (for the quiz to run) is in this link: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/70pbcb80kss2k9e/stats_quiz.dat`

`main()` needs to be edited to use the proper data file address:

The complete error message I received is below. This is weird because I initialized `e` right before the while-loop. I hope someone can help me resolve this problem. Thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#217>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Dropbox/folder/stats_quiz_feb24_2013.py", line 83, in main
    while not e:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Aside: the line `score_name = score = name = []` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't make three lists, it makes *one* list, and binds three names to it.  Try that at the console and then `score.append(3); print (score, score_name, name)`.  It probably doesn't matter here because you rebind `score` and `name`, but still.

Comment: Ugh, I totally forgot about the issue of reference (coming from R, which doesn't have this issue). Thanks for the pointing that out!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a minimal self-contained example.

Comment: I don't know how this could be reproduced- there must be something in the code we can't see. Can you try making a reproducible example- that is, a short version of the code that can be run and produces this error? (It is likely that in the process of doing so, you will discover what is causing the problem in the first place).

Comment: The full code works for me. Please provide a minimal failing code, not this monstrosity.

Comment: I've edited the question to reduce it to what I think is going on.

Comment: So I was wrong to not point out the name clash in the first place.

Comment: I added `print(e)` right below `while not e`. It seems that `e` was initially recognized. But when the loop got to the end of the pickle object, for some reason it stopped recognizing it.

Comment: Ah, that name clash was intended... LOL.

Comment: @wRAR: Yes, I want the value of `e` to be changed after an exception arises.

Comment: @Alex then changed it inside the `except` clause, though I don't know why you don't just use `break` as is proposed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't know what's causing the actual problem, but why don't you just use `break` when an exception occurs? Your loop becomes:

```
while True:
    try:
        score = pickle.load(score_list)
        name = pickle.load(score_list)
        score_name.append([score, name])
    except EOFError as e:
        break
```

As far as I know, this is the idiomatic way of achieving "run loop while there's no exception"

**Edit: Why this happens**

It would seem that in python3, once you exit the scope of an exception handler, the variable that the exception was bound to is removed from the namespace. I modified the code to the following:

```
def main():
    e = None
    print(locals())
    while not e:
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        print(locals())

main()
```

Output:

```
{'e': None}
{}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in main
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
```

This is not the case in python2. Given that the syntax was changed for how you assign an exception to a variable, I'm not surprised that the semantics of it were changed as well. Although I do think that this is "surprising" behaviour(in the sense that it is not what you would expect).

In any case, the proper way to exit a loop when an exception occurs is in the code above. If you want to keep the exception outside of the exception handler's scope I guess you could still do something like this:

```
def main():
   e = None
   print(locals())
   while not e:
      try:
         raise Exception
      except Exception as ex:
         e = ex
      print(locals())

main()
```

Which produces the following output:

```
{'e': None}
{'e': Exception()}
```

But you really shouldn't be doing that for your particular use-case.

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution and the explanation! Much appreciated

Comment: nymk's answer has a much better explanation than mine about why this happens given that my experience with python3 is limited. The PEP he links to is particularly instructional if you have time to read it :)

Answer (score 15):

This error is caused by the new `try...except...` scope, which is a Python 3 feature.
See [PEP-3110](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/)

In Python 3, the following block

```
try:
    try_body
except E as N:
    except_body
...
```

gets translated to (in Python 2.5 terms)

```
try:
    try_body
except E, N:
    try:
        except_body
    finally:
        N = None
        del N
...
```

Therefore, this function in Python 3

```
def main():
    e = None
    print(locals())
    while not e:
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

is equivalent to

```
def main():
    e = None
    print(locals())
    if not e:
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        del e
    if not e:
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        del e
    ...
```

`e` was initialized, but it has been deleted after the first `try except` block.
Thus, `UnboundLocalError` is inevitbale.

Comment: I haven't been using python3 too much(I'm still stuck in my old python2 ways for now). Thank you for that explanation :) I guessed the problem was changed semantics from python2 to python3 but couldn't figure out exactly how

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I just started using Python, and was told by my friends that there are quite a few inconvenient differences between 3 and 2. (my friends only use python 2)